# New Rmd document: knitr: Error in library("rstudio") : there is no package called 'rstudio'

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

firing up "RStudio" V1.0.136 on my Mac, just as usual, creating a new file, a Rmd, and trying--as I've done countless time before--knitr it just as is, but this time a strange error message occurs:

```
Error in library("rstudio") : there is no package called 'rstudio'
```

Never ever have seen this before, and I haven't got the faintest clue as why this has popped into existence, and how to remedy it.

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, after wiping my whole RStudio and R installation, with a subsequent re-installation thereof, all is working fine again.